# PHP5 Ubuntu not updated?

Tags: 12.04, php

I just installed php5 on my newly setup Ubuntu Server 12.04. However, I noticed why does the PHP version is kind of too low? As compared to the official PHP.net website, the recent version is at PHP 5.4.17 or PHP 5.3.27. Is there anything I am missing?

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Mar 11 2013 14:31:48)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that is the currently supported version available for Ubuntu 12.04. Canonical does not always release patches to items such as PHP and MySQL for the LTS releases until it has had time to vet them with their testing. I have the same versions of Server and PHP. You are certainly able to download, configure and install the newer version of PHP if you so desire.

Comment: If so, how would that be?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php and start following instructions